# Having issues with grunt installation

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I followed the documentation on [grunt site](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started). After executing `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli` I got this output

```
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
    /usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
    grunt-cli@0.1.11 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
    ├── resolve@0.3.1
    ├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
    └── findup-sync@0.1.2 (lodash@1.0.1, glob@3.1.21)
```

After this, when I do `grunt` I get this message

```
    grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.11)

    Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

    If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
    hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
    installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

    http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

After this I also followed [this link](https://github.com/gillesfabio/soja/issues/1) to solve my problem but I still am getting the same error above.

**UPDATE**

Gruntfile.js

```
    module.exports = function () {
        grunt.initConfig({
            min: {
                dist: {
                    src: 'file-one.js',
                    dest: 'file-one.min.js'
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

package.json file

```
    {
      "name": "grunt",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.1.11",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
        "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a Gruntfile and package.json?

Answer (score 7):

You have installed `grunt-cli` as a global package, but you also need to install `grunt` locally. The `grunt-cli` package installs a global command line tool, but that command line tool just tries to load the locally install `grunt` module. This is done in order to allow people to have multiple versions of grunt for different projects, you need to have grunt itself installed as a local package in the project you are working on.

From the page you linked to:

> Note that installing grunt-cli does not install the Grunt task runner! The job of the Grunt CLI is simple: run the version of Grunt which has been installed next to a Gruntfile. This allows multiple versions of Grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.

So you need to have `grunt` as a local dependency in your package.json file, just like any other module, wheres you would not list `grunt-cli` in there.

Comment: I have package.json and Gruntfile.js files in my project. Please see my updated question.

Comment: But have you actually installed `grunt`, or just listed it in your package.json? Try running npm install or specifically npm install grunt@0.1.11

Comment: I already done npm installed and it installed grunt. But now I am getting this error `Warning: Task "min" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.` when I run `grunt min` command.

Comment: @2619 You have a config for `min` and are attempting to run it, but from what you have shown, there is no such task. If you are trying to run `uglify`, you need to name your task and config that.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I config min task in my above example?

Comment: What are you expecting your `min` task to do? If you you are expecting it to uglify, then you should name it `uglify`, not `min`.

Answer (score 0):

`npm update` work for me. Grunt have to be updated.